# Grails webflow url rewriting

Tags: grails

Want to make the URLs SEO friendly when using grails webflow. It is quite limiting with the convention grails uses and hard to go around the way it's built. 
For example, i have a flow called fooProcess in the controller called FooController, when i trigger the flow i would like the display: /foo/bar/test, instead of /foo/fooProcess?excecution=e1s2

```
class FooController {
 def fooProcessFlow {
   showFoo {
   }
 }
}
```

I tried using redirect and specify the uri but that's not supported, grails complains that the page isn't found

```
fooProcessFlow {
 showFoo {                              
   redirect(uri:"/foo/bar/test")    
 }
}
```

grails/foo/fooProcess.dispatch/externalRedirect:/foo/bar/test

Also, a redirect is an end state in a flow, if I only want to render the page, i have to  use the render method and specify the view name or structure my views according to webflow convention.

```
fooProcessFlow {
 showFoo {                              
   render(view:"/foo/bar/test") 
   on "add".to "add"
 }
}
```

The url will be in this case

```
/foo/fooProcessProcess?execution=e6s1
```

Anyone dealt with this case before ?

Did anyone use UrlRweriteFilter with webflows in grails 
http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/

ken

Answer (score -1):

You can use **URLMappings** Grails Plugin

See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Plug-ins/URL%20mappings.html

Edit this file: *grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy*

Putting something like this inside:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        "/foo/bar/test" (controller: "foo", action: "fooProcessFlow")

        "/$controller/$action?/$ids?"{
            constraints {
            }
        }
    }
}
```